# How to grep ifconfig and replace in file?

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a script that greps the eth0 ip address and put it the 6th line in a specific file.

I have tried this

```
newip= $(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
sed -i 6s/.*/$newip/ file.txt
```

But this doesn't work, it writes an empty line
What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try didn't worked for you because of space between equal sign `=` and variable definition.

Answer (score 0):

seems that the newip variable should be this way

```
newip=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d: -f 2)
sed -i 6s/.*/$newip/ file.txt
```

this way it works perfectly, first awk then cut